# Partial keyword search on joomla smart search?

Tags: joomla-3.x

In my current installation of the smart search plugin with default settings  if I search for "home" instead of "homepage", no results appear.

Is it possible to customize Joomla's smart search plugin to show results for partial keywords?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem using the smart search module of Joomla.

There are results of partial keywords when using the default search module of Joomla, but not in the smart search module. This is not very smart or is it a setting?

Comment: Hi Digin. Welcome to JSE :) Please be aware that your comment has been posted as an answer and is likely to attract negative votes. Unfortunately,  you won't be able to add a comment yet because you do not have enough points.